# Grouping multiple rows in a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I am a python newbie working on version 2.7.  Below is a sample of the data frame that I am working with. There are additional columns that are not relevant to the problem so they are not included in the below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( { "Name" : ["BROD", "BROD", "BROD", "BROD", "SSBD" , "SSBD","SSBD","SSBD"] , 
                     "Digit" : ["F", "F", "T", "T", "F", "F", "T", "T"],
                     "ID": ["A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"],
                     "Date": ["2/3/2010","2/3/2010","2/3/2010","2/3/2010","3/4/2007","3/4/2007","3/4/2007","3/4/2007"],
                     "Base" : ["CAD","CAD","CAD","CAD","CAD","CAD","CAD","CAD"],
                     "Term" : ["USD","USD","JPY","JPY","EUR","EUR","JPY","JPY"],
                     "Amt": [100.00,100.00,9082.00,9082.00,60.00,60.00,7387.80,7387.80]})
```

There are multiple duplicate values.  Each row represents a component of a trade and the ID column groups them into one trade.  I would like to create a new data frame that only includes one row for each trade.  The data frame would look like this:

```
ID    Date       Name     Buy   Sell    Buy Amt Sell Amt
A    2/3/2010    BROD     USD   JPY     100.00   9082.00
B    3/4/2007    SSBD     EUR   JPY     60.00    7387.80
```

Where for each ID, if the Digit = F then the value in the Term column is placed in the Buy column and the value in the Amt column is placed in the Buy Amt column.  If the Digit = T then the value in the Term column is placed in the Sell column and the value in the Amt column is placed in the Sell Amount column.

Please point me in the right direction for the most efficient way to solve this problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `np.where` and then `groupby`

```
df['Buy'] = np.where((df['Digit'] == 'F'), df['Term'], np.nan)

df['Sell'] = np.where((df['Digit'] == 'T'), df['Term'], np.nan)

df['BuyAmt'] = np.where((df['Digit'] == 'F'), df['Amt'], np.nan)
df['SellAmt'] = np.where((df['Digit'] == 'T'), df['Amt'], np.nan)

df.drop(['Digit','Base','Term','Amt'], axis=1, inplace= True)

df = df.groupby('ID').first()

print(df)
    Name      Date  Buy Sell  BuyAmt  SellAmt
ID                                           
A   BROD  2/3/2010  USD  JPY   100.0   9082.0
B   SSBD  3/4/2007  EUR  JPY    60.0   7387.8
```

Also if you need your column in order like you posted, you can use `pandas reindex`

Answer (score 0):

I assume duplicates should be dropped, else you need to explain better how identical rows should be handled:

```
>>> df2 = df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then we create two dataframes, one for 'F' and one for 'T', create the `Buy`/`Sell` and `Buy Amt`/`Sell Amt` for each, and drop unused columns:

```
>>> df_F = df2[df2.Digit == 'F'].assign(**{'Buy': lambda x: x.Term, 'Buy Amt': lambda x: x.Amt})
...                             .drop(['Digit', 'Base', 'Term', 'Amt'], axis=1)
>>> df_T = df2[df2.Digit == 'T'].assign(**{'Sell': lambda x: x.Term, 'Sell Amt': lambda x: x.Amt})
...                             .drop(['Digit', 'Base', 'Term', 'Amt'], axis=1)
```

Finally, we merge the two dataframes, and rearrange the column order:

```
>>> merged = df_F.merge(df_T, on=['ID', 'Name', 'Date'])
>>> merged[['ID', 'Date', 'Name', 'Buy', 'Sell', 'Buy Amt', 'Sell Amt']]
  ID      Date  Name  Buy Sell  Buy Amt  Sell Amt
0  A  2/3/2010  BROD  USD  JPY    100.0    9082.0
1  B  3/4/2007  SSBD  EUR  JPY     60.0    7387.8
```

That's it. If 'ID' should be the index, you can use `merged.set_index('ID')`